# Why GitHub hosting a .NET app is not working

Tags: github

I was told a few days back GitHub will let you deploy a free (basic) website.

My first attempt with an HTML, CSS, Javascript website was successful.

However, When I tried to deploy a simple test ASP.NET, even though there was no error, the website was not showing at all.

Does GitHub let you deploy a test .NET website? Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not.  GitHub Pages is designed for static websites; that is, websites with only static HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.  There is no support for any backend whatever.

If you want to host a service with a backend component, you'll need to find other options.